# Presenting viewController with transition is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to present a view controller, and it always kind of fades in,from the bottom, and looks very strange while it appears. This happens irrespective of whatever type of animation is set here.

This is my current code :

```
UIViewController *mainV=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"browserViewIP"];

    CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 1;
    transition.type = kCATransitionFromLeft;
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
    [self.view.window.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
    [self presentViewController:mainV animated:YES completion:nil];//also set to NO .
```

Need some guidance here on what could be going wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: So, you don't want the faded background thing? What do you mean by very strange? Anyways, try [self.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition]; and see if that's the thing you want or not.

Comment: yes it did worked. thank you very much. put it as an answer and i will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the animation to view's layer directly, not on window's layer.

Replace

```
[self.view.window.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
```

with

```
[self.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
```